# How do I pass the user touch from one object to another object?

Tags: objective-c, drag-and-drop

I am developing an application that allows the user at a certain point to drag and drop 10 images around. So there are 10 images, and if he/she drags one image onto another, these two are swapped.

A screenshot of how this looks like:

[image: Screenshot of application]

So when the user drags one photo I want it to reduce its opacity and give the user a draggable image on his finger which disappears again if he drops it outside of any image.

The way I have developed this is the following. I have set a `UIPanGesture` for these `UIImageView`s as:

```
for (UIImageView *imgView in editPhotosView.subviews) {
        UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(photoDragged:)];
        [imgView addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];

        imgView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

        [panGesture release];
}
```

Then my `photoDragged:` method:

```
- (void)photoDragged:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture {

    UIView *view = gesture.view;
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
        UIImageView *imgView = (UIImageView *)view;
        if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
            imgView.alpha = 0.5;

            UIImageView *newView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:imgView.frame];
            newView.image = imgView.image;            
            newView.tag = imgView.tag;
            newView.backgroundColor = imgView.backgroundColor;
            newView.gestureRecognizers = imgView.gestureRecognizers;

            [editPhotosView addSubview:newView];            
            [newView release];
        }
        else if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
            CGPoint translation = [gesture translationInView:view.superview];
            [view setCenter:CGPointMake(view.center.x + translation.x, view.center.y + translation.y)];
            [gesture setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:view.superview];
        }
        else { ... }
    }
}
```

Thus as you see I add a new `UIImageView` with 0.5 opacity on the same spot as the original image when the user starts dragging it. So the user is dragging the **original** image around. But what I **want to do** is to copy the **original** image when the user drags it and create a "draggable" image and pass that to the user to drag around.

But to do that I have to pass the user touch on to the newly created "draggable" UIImageView. While it's actually set to the original image (the one the user touches when he starts dragging).

So my question is: **How do I pass the user's touch to another element?**.

I hope that makes sense. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why not just drag the ORIGINAL image, and leave a COPY at the original place?

Comment: @PragamOnce That is what I am doing at the moment. But my mind tells me that's an odd thing to do. And an issue is that my copy afterwards cannot be dragged anymore. Seems like the gestureRecognizers are lost, even though that I copy them (see code above).

Comment: Not sure why you think that's odd. Gesture recognizers can only be associated with a single view (because they have the view property, it wouldn't make sense for them to be associated with multiple views along with other reasons). You need to recreate that gesture and then associate it with the copy...i am programming something very similar and that's how i did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I decided to indeed drag the original image and leave a copy at the original place.

I solved the issue with the gesture recognizers I was having by re-creating them and assigning them to the "copy", just like PragmaOnce suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can pass the UIPanGestureRecognizer object to another object by creating a method in your other object which takes the gesture recognizer as a parameter.

```
- (void)myMethod:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

And call from your current gesture recognizer using....

```
[myOtherObject myMethod:gesture];
```

Not entirely sure I'm understanding your question here fully. :-/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
[otherObject sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Or any other UIControlEvent